# What is the value of a let expression

Tags: functional-programming, f#

From what I understand, every code in f# is an expression, including `let` binding.
Say we got the following code:

```
let a = 5
printfn "%d" a
```

I've read that this would be seen by the compiler as

```
let a = 5 in
(
     printfn "%d" a
)
```

And so the value of all this would be value of inner expression, which is value of `printf`. On the other hand, in f# interactive:

```
> let a = 5;;
val a : int = 5
```

Which clearly indicates that the value of let expression is the value bound to the identifier.

**Q: Can anyone explain what is the value of a let expression? Can it be different in compiled code than in F# interactive?**

Comment: many languages use a fundamentally different setup in interactive mode than in compiled mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several contexts in F# where a `let` may appear, including:

- The context of *module definitions*, where *value definitions* use the `let` keyword.  Definitions do not return or have a value in the same sense as expressions.
- The context of *expressions*, where *value definition expressions* use the `let` keyword.  To simplify, value definition expressions are basically of the form `let p = i in b`, where `p` is a pattern and `i` and `b` are expressions, and the value of such an expressions is the value of the `b` expression.

The context in F# interactive is like the context of module definitions.  In the case of value definitions, the F# interactive helpfully prints out some information on the defined value.

Note that the above contexts are not the only contexts where `let` appears.  For example, *class type definitions* may contain *value definitions* using the `let` keyword.  See [The F# Language Specification](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/) for more details.